# Defining gem version in Gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems, version

What is best when creating a gem:

1. defining the version as a string in the gemspec, or
2. referencing SomeGem::VERSION constant, stored in SomeGem/version for the version?

I realise that I can do either but I want to understand what is best practice and **why** that is.

If there is another way that I'm not familiar with please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As you point out, they are both different means to the same end, but best practice (and the default behavior when you run `bundle gem`) is (2): referencing SomeGem::VERSION. A couple of advantages to this approach:

- Gem version is always available:

  `puts Mygem::VERSION # => 0.0.1`
- If I want to see only the git commits where the version number changed, I can run:

  `git log version.rb`

Comment: Thanks @alex. Good answer. I'll leave this unanswered for a couple of days to see if anyone else has something to add.